# VS2010 - one pinned icon where all opened solutions will stack to and will display recent projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have the following exe pinned in the start menu:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

however, it does not display any recent projects, even though I have many.

I pinned this to the task bar and all solutions opened get stack over it - which is desired and expected. However, when I right click it, it does not display the recent projects. Somewhere I read that I need to pin

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe"
```

in order to have recent projects, which I did and indeed it shows them, however, the opened solutions are still on the other icon (devenv.exe)
So, how can I just have one icon pinned in the task bar where the opened solutions will stack to and will display recent projects upon right click.

Comment: The first path is OK - i just checked mine and it's exactly the same. Maybe try pinning it by clicking the shortcut in Start Menu/

Comment: I did, but it did not help :(